# Draw.IO: Foreign Key on SQL Plugin

Tags: draw.io

Does Draw.IO support foreign key relationships?
Tested it with a lot of different SQL samples [(w3schools sql foreignkey)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp) but none worked.

Comment: seems it's not implemented yet.. going to implement it and will post a complete answer to all the supported SQL types i develop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to budget issues i was only able to implement it to work with MySQL and SQL Server and SQL Server Generated Scripts.
The pull request is pending on https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/pull/233.

MySQL Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (OrderID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

SQL Server Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
PersonID int,
LastName varchar(255),
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);

CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    CONSTRAINT FK_PersonOrder FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)
    REFERENCES Persons(PersonID)
);
```

SQL Server Generated Script Example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Applications](
    [ApplicationName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredApplicationName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](256) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicationId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [LoweredApplicationName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicationName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Users](
    [ApplicationId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [LoweredUserName] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
    [MobileAlias] [nvarchar](16) NULL,
    [IsAnonymous] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [LastActivityDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO


ALTER TABLE [dbo].[aspnet_Users]  WITH CHECK ADD FOREIGN KEY([ApplicationId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[aspnet_Applications] ([ApplicationId])
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

I rewrote the sql parser by @brunomartinspro to be more forgiving on spaces and case sensativity and support more sql database types. Also foreign key relationships now work and are drawn properly<s>, just waiting for pr to be merged in.</s>

https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/pull/3091

Update:
New pr with single file change https://github.com/jgraph/drawio/pull/4122. Much easier to install locally and some notes. I'm expecting it to be rejected since the `sql.js` plugin is no longer maintained and the drawio project is closed source.

[image: sql import fk preview]

Answer (score 1):

The PR was merged, you can access this plugin via Arrange, Insert, From SQL at https://www.draw.io/?splash=0&p=sql

[image: Using the SQL plugin]

Comment: That didn't work properly for all types of SQL, specially generated SQL.
I made a PR to add the features described on the answer.
That GIF is no longer updated since 2016.
https://brunomartins.pro/public/drawio/plugins/sql/DIO.PNG